# How to test an ignition key switch voltage drop with an Arduino Uno microcontroller?

Tags: microcontroller

How to test an ignition key switch voltage drop with an Arduino Uno microcontroller?

I want to test thr voltage drop across OFF and ON key positions with an Arduino.

The operating voltage of the ignition key switch is 14VDC and the Arduino operating voltage is 3.3-5VDC. If I connect the ignition key output direct to the Arduino, it will burn.

How can I test this?

Comment: Use a resistive dividier to step the voltage down and run it through a comparator before feeding to the Arduino. You may use another resistisve divider on the other input of the comparator connected to your 3.3V-5V and choose the ratio to set your threshold value.

Comment: hi @DKNguyen, is there any specific circuit or module for this.?

Comment: You’ll need two resistors in series, try 18k and 10k for 5V or 33k and 10k for 3.3V.  Connect the larger value resistor to the ignition switch, and the smaller value resistor to ground, then connect both resistors and an Arduino input pin all together.  That should be ok if you just want an on/off indication; if you want to measure the actual voltage from the switch then you should replace the 10k resistor with a slightly lower value e.g. 8.2k to be sure that the ADC stays below its maximum range.  Make sense?

Comment: If you need to ask basic questions like this, you probably shouldn't be fiddling around with car battery voltages in the first place. Start with current limited 5V circuits while you learn electronics.

Answer (score 0):

As Lundin comments, please learn some basic electronics.

Anyway, here is the most simple circuit.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqRMps.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

It is designed to divide the car voltage for a 3.3V Arduino. If you use a 5V Arduino it will work also, but you might lower R1 from 33k to 18k or 22k.

The [voltage divider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_divider) follows this equation:

$$
\frac{R2}{R1 + R2} = \frac{V_{Arduino}}{V_{Ignition}}
$$

Rearranging for R1 leads to:

$$
R1 = R2 * (\frac{V_{Ignition}}{V_{Arduino}} - 1)
$$

You may select any resistor from the [E12 (or even E6) series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_series_of_preferred_numbers) that has the next higher value.

For example, for \$V_{Arduino} = 3.3V\$ you will get \$R1 \approx 32.42k\Omega\$. So you will use a \$33k\Omega\$ resistor.

Each resistor has a rated maximum power dissipation. One form of calculation is \$P = U^2 / R\$. In the circuit R1 takes the most power because it has the highest voltage. Let's see:

$$
P = (V_{Ignition} - V_{Arduino})^2 / R1
$$

$$
P = (14V - 3.3V) / 33k\Omega \approx 3.5mW
$$

$$
P = (14V - 5V) / 18k\Omega = 4.5mW
$$

Any common resistor will take that power.

**EDIT:**

This is just the start to make the voltages digestible for the Arduino.

To measure the **voltage drop**, you will need additionally, at least:

- A second voltage divider for the voltage of the battery
- A bit bigger R1 to enlarge the range to higher voltages as 14V, if you need to consider this
- Precautions against voltage spikes
- Filters depending on your frequency requirements, analog or in software
- Software to measure both inputs and calculate the difference (some Arduino's microcontroller might have a differential mode)

Comment: Also, TVS is pretty much mandatory on this kind of automotive electronics. Around 18V or so and it should be placed before the voltage divider.

Comment: This is however only the hardware part of the solution, because once you have this properly connected to an MCU ADC input, all manner of digital filtering is necessary. Some manner of hysteresis or moving average to deal with SAR ADC fluctuations. Some manner of filter to weed out the spikes and signal bounces. And then a voltage level check/comparator for where the ignition can be considered active, since it will come with a _big_ voltage surge and drop down to some ~6V before it stabilizes, which might take several seconds.

Comment: That won't tell you the voltage drop across the switch, only the voltage after the switch. Considering another position on the switch usually operates a solenoid, and the solenoid connects a very high current load, the battery voltage feeding the switch probably varies a lot too.